# Payment gateway integration - Javascript not working

Tags: javascript, php, payment-gateway, ccavenue

I am integrating CCAvenue Payment gateway to my code.

```
echo '<form method="post" name="redirect" action="'.$url.'">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="encRequest" value="'.$encrypted_data.'">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="access_code" value="'.$this->access_code.'">';
echo '</form>';
echo '<script language="javascript">document.redirect.submit();</script>';
```

My page is not redirecting to `$url`.

I added `<INPUT TYPE="submit" value="submit">` to `<form>`. Now `Submit` button is visible on the page. Click of submit button redirects me to payment page.

This script auto redirects only on IE 11. It does not work on Chrome, Firefox dev edition.

**I tried**

1. **Delay (Alert not executing)**

   `echo '<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">';`
   `echo 'function redirectToCC() {document.redirect.submit();alert("hi");};function delay() {setTimeout(redirectToCC, 1000)};delay();';`
   `echo '</script>';`
2. **Change file permissions**

I changed this file's permission to 755

3. **jQuery**

I added `id` "btnSubmit" to `<INPUT TYPE="submit" value="submit">` in `<form>`

```
echo '<script language="javascript">$(document).ready(function(){$("#btnSubmit").click();});</script>';  
echo '<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.slim.min.js"></script>';
```

4. **JS click()**

   `var link = document.getElementById('btnSubmit');link.click();`

It seems that javascript is not executing on this page. Any hint / reference?

Comment: i dont understand why you would display a form only to instantly submit it, forums are for user interaction

Comment: Actually this is payment integration code where I have to `POST` user's encrypted data, and access code. After this, payment gateway will decrypt the data , and show payment form. So actually, I have to post this data, and redirect to gateway page.

Comment: you should be using CURL then

Answer (score 1):

calling via Script language directly is a little iffy due to timing issues.
And your JQuery example doesn't have any JQuery, just javascript.

Here's how I would do this (Note that the 'name' is now an 'id')

```
<html><body onload=document.getElementById('redirect').submit()>
<form id='redirect' action='$url' method='post'>
// Info
</form></body></html>
```

Then the form will auto submit upon creation. The onload call is only triggered after the complete website loads so you don't have timing issues.

Comment: I will try this code. I placed wrong code under `jQuery` heading. I updated it now.

Comment: Ok I see the issue with Jquery.  .click() event is different than .submit().

Comment: Script is executing after adding onload() with setTimeout() - 1st thing I tried. I will check and mention exact problem here.